# Two results in a row with two columns and group

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to mix multiple results on a single line

Here the data example:

```
TOPICS
    topicID   state    title
    1           A     'Hello'
    1           B     'Bye'
    2           A     'Great'
```

And mixed with:

```
STUDENTS
        topicID   studentID
        1            23
        1            27
        2            33
        2            40
```

I want this result:

```
Topic     A         B      Students
1      'Hello'    'Bye'     23,27
2      'Great'     null     33,40
```

Now I correctly receive users using GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT studentID SEPARATOR ',') in SELECT but i can't use it again. I have tried CASE but have not succeeded.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation and a correlated subquery:

```
select t.topicid,
       max(case when t.state = 'A' then t.title end) as a,
       max(case when t.state = 'B' then t.title end) as b,
       (select group_concat(s.studentid)
        from students s
        where s.topicid = t.topicid
       ) as students
from topics t
group by topicid;
```

The correlated subquery eliminates the need for `group_concat(distinct)`, which is more expensive than just `group_concat()`.